# Change default recording sample rate for "arecord"

Tags: alsa, recording

I'm attempting to change the default sample rate when **recording audio** with `arecord`.

Currently, when running `arecord test.wav` the rate is 8000 Hz:

```
arecord test.wav
Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
```

I can change the sample rate using the rate flag `--rate 44100`:

```
arecord --format S16_LE --rate 44100 test.wav
Recording WAVE 'test.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Mono
```

But when I change the rate in `asound.conf`, it has no effect on recording (rate stays at 8000 Hz). Am I missing something?

My `asound.conf`:

```
# The IPC key of dmix or dsnoop plugin must be unique
# If 555555 or 666666 is used by other processes, use another one

# use samplerate to resample as speexdsp resample is bad
defaults.pcm.rate_converter "samplerate"

pcm.!default {
    type asym
    playback.pcm "playback"
    capture.pcm "capture"
}

pcm.playback {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "dmixed"
}

pcm.capture {
    type plug
    slave.pcm "array"
}

pcm.dmixed {
    type dmix
    slave.pcm "hw:wm8960soundcard"
    ipc_key 555555
}

pcm.array {
    type dsnoop
    slave {
        pcm "hw:1,0"
        format S16_LE
        rate 44100
        channels 1
    }
    ipc_key 666666
}
```

Ouput of `arecord -L`

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
default
eci
eco
usbstream:CARD=Headphones
    bcm2835 Headphones
    USB Stream Output
sysdefault:CARD=wm8960soundcard
    wm8960-soundcard, bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=wm8960soundcard,DEV=0
    wm8960-soundcard, bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=wm8960soundcard,DEV=0
    wm8960-soundcard, bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=wm8960soundcard,DEV=0
    wm8960-soundcard, bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=wm8960soundcard,DEV=0
    wm8960-soundcard, bcm2835-i2s-wm8960-hifi wm8960-hifi-0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
usbstream:CARD=wm8960soundcard
    wm8960-soundcard
    USB Stream Output
```

**Addition**

How to change the default `arecord` sample rate when using PJUSA(PJSIP):

PJUSA initializes ALSA at launch:

```
11:56:12.951     alsa_dev.c  ..ALSA driver found 32 devices
11:56:12.951     alsa_dev.c  ..ALSA initialized
```

`alsa_dev.c` is located at `pjproject/pjmedia/src/pjmedia-audiodev/alsa_dev.c`

The default sample rate is set in line 270:

```
/* Set the default sample rate */
adi->default_samples_per_sec = 8000;
```

Just change the value to the desired sample rate (microphone has to be capable of that sample rate).

Comment: Can you please post the output of arecord -L ?

Comment: Added the output to my inital post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the documentation for `arecord` (see `man arecord`) it writes,

> `-r`, `--rate=#<Hz>` Sampling rate in Hertz. The default rate is 8000 Hertz. [...]

So you can see that the rate is not controlled through `asound.conf`; it's controlled using this command-line flag.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is another way for other apps (e.g. PJUSA; works with ALSA) to manipulate that rate?

Comment: Nevermind - just solved this question myself. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will add this additional info to my original post.